# Django Project Live not Collecting Static

Tags: python, css, django

I have a django project which is deployed on a webserver http://beta.reichmann.ro:8000/. The thing is that it doesnt collect the static files. I run python manage.py collectstatic, but somehow the path is broken. The it from the site told me that the server searches for beta.reichmann.ro:8000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css. My settings are:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'contact.apps.ContactConfig',
    # am pus asta aici cand am creat for apliktie noua.for se ia din apps din apliktia contact si settings--contactconfig
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'posts',
  ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chn.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',

            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'chn.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ro'
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Bucharest'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env", "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro", "our_static"),)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env", "media_root")

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

Can someone please explain me the steps i have to do to make my css working?[image]

Thank you,
Ionut

Comment: Apart from anything else, you certainly have STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS the wrong way round. STATIC_ROOT is the place static files are collected *to* (and served from).

Comment: i have another static in pro folder. but can you pls help me in order to point me where is my bug?

Answer (score 1):

keep your static folder directly under root directory and then change the path as

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), "static_in_env", "static_root")
```

also, make sure your static folder has required permission to read from.

if you still have problem serving static files you can do this in your wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xx_app.settings")
#application = get_wsgi_application()
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
```

Comment: Thank you! it didn;t help! the structure is fine. The way how it is is running perfectly on my notebook. On the server it sucks as it doesn't displays the css.

Comment: i know i have faced the same problem with pythonanywhere when i tried to upload my project, but my problem was solved by putting the files directly under the root folder and changing the folder permission to read for all.

Comment: thank you! Currently i have your settings in place and they still aren't rendered

Comment: yes Sir! (chn) root@localhost:~/chn/chn# python3 manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /root/static_in_env/static_root

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes

0 static files copied to '/root/static_in_env/static_root', 2111 unmodified.

Comment: i took it outside of root and is showing:     STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), "static_in_env", "static_root"))
TypeError: dirname() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: yeah that is because of syntax error. it should be
`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname‌​(BASE_DIR))), "static_in_env", "static_root") `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163664/discussion-between-sumeet-kumar-and-cohen).

Comment: @Cohen i have updated this answer. Glad i was of some help.